# update manager fails, apt-get update stops at 93%

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

My updates will not install on Ubuntu 12.04.  It gets to 93% and then gets an error of an (address not found) No host name associated with http(ubuntu.com/etc. etc.

I have used the command: `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update; && sudo apt-get upgrade`.  But it stalls on 93%.  I really need to fix this problem as it will not let me take updates.

My update manager says no authentic or something like that.  Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you got Google Chrome installed? Could you share the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with us?

Comment: Can you post the commands / links in the update process where it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well some days ago. You'll have to change the update server used by your system. Within Software-center click Edit-Menu-->Software-Sources, Tab: Ubuntu-Software.  Click on "Download from ............", and choose "other". In the opening Window click "Select best server", wait for result and accept what it found. Reload outdated information about available software. It seems ubuntu is not allways able to connect to the expected server for some reason.

After this procedure the update was finished in my case.